# Is there a better way to parse a file in python?

Tags: python

I am looking for some better way to parse a huge file.
Following is the example of the file.

sample.txt

```
'abcdefghi'
'xyzwfg'
'lmnop'
```

Out of which I am looking for 'abc' and 'xyz' in the file at least once

I was able to find them but I am looking for some better way.
Following is my code

```
datafile = file('sample.txt')
abc = 0
xyz = 0
found - True

for line in datafile:
        if 'abc' in line:
            abc += 1
            break    
for line in datafile:
        if 'xyz' in line:
            xyz += 1
            break

if (abc + xyz) >= 2:
    print 'found'
else:
    print 'fail'
```

I am running a loop twice. So is there a better way to parse the file?

Comment: Do you care about the total number of occurrences found?  Your use of a counter instead of a true/false flag suggests yes, but the use of `break` suggests no.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code will produce incorrect results if you `'xyz'` occurs before `'abc'`.  To fix this test for both in the same loop.

```
with open('sample.txt') as datafile:
    abc_found = False
    xyz_found = False

    for line in datafile:
        if 'abc' in line:
            abc_found = True
        if 'xyz' in line:
            xyz_found = True
        if abc_found and xyz_found: 
            break # stop looking if both found
```

Comment: @FredrikRosenqvist:  He does not seek to 0 or close and reopen the file, so the second loop continues reading the file where the first one left off.

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is subjective and there are no metrics provided to define it. However, a simple optimization is the following:

```
for line in datafile:
    if 'abc' in line:
        abc += 1
    if 'xyz' in line:
        xyz += 1
```

If the actual problem is that the file is indeed very large, you want to only read one line at a time:

```
f = open('myTextFile.txt', "r")
line = f.readline()
while line:
    if 'abc' in line:
        abc += 1
    if 'xyz' in line:
        xyz += 1
    line = f.readline()
```

The result of this would be to get the number of lines in which `abc` and `xyz` occurred, respectively. If the idea is to quit as soon as you find a single matching line, then including the `break` is appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to answer.  However note that this will process the **whole** file, where the original code stops looking after one occurrence is found.

Comment: True... though it's unclear from the original question if that's intentional. If so, why use `+=`?

Comment: The idiomatic way to read a file line by line is `for line in f:`.  No need for the awkward while loop and explicit calls to `f.readline()`.